# How to drag a node from one column div to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I've done my best to search for someone with a similar question, and while they are out there, they don't match what I need to do. As such, I wasn't able to solve my problem by reading the answers to theirs. I've spent the latter part of the past 5 hours working on this, and I figured out much of what I needed to do, but I finally ran into a problem that I couldn't figure out, or solve.

The use case is that I am going to dynamically build a 'column'. I want to be able to drag an item from Column A over to Column B (and vice verse). Once an item is dragged to the other column, it should get removed from the original column.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/c5zdbve3/) is a link to a JSFiddle page that has the code I was testing on. As it sits right now it works perfectly fine exactly one time. When I attempt to use it a second time nothing happens. Best I can tell is that the 'handleDragStart' event listener is not firing a second time; as a result, when loaded from an ASP.Net Web Form, I get the following error in the browser client when I attempt to move a second item:`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look, I have posted only the required code

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var elementId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementId));
}
```

```css
.column {
  width: 75px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #6772E5;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="columns" style="width: 240px;">
  <div id="columna" class="column" style="float:left;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <header>Unlocked</header>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" id="a" ondragstart="drag(event)">A</div>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" id="b" ondragstart="drag(event)">B</div>

  </div>
  <div id="columnb" class="column" style="float:right;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
    <header>Locked</header>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" id="c" ondragstart="drag(event)">C</div>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" id="d" ondragstart="drag(event)">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**
I have added an id to each of the nodes, if you don't like to use ids you can do it this way

```js
var draggedElement;

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  draggedElement = ev.target;
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.appendChild(draggedElement);
}
```

```css
.column {
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #6772E5;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="columns" style="width: 240px;">
  <div id="columna" class="column" style="float:left;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <header>Unlocked</header>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">A</div>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">B</div>

  </div>
  <div id="columnb" class="column" style="float:right;" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
    <header>Locked</header>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">C</div>
    <div class="obj" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! You are a life saver. I was reading that before I tested it and I didn't think it was going to work the way I wanted. In my mind you have to remove the node from one, and add it to the other. Am puzzled why it worked, but it worked! Thanks :D

Comment: It works because the appendChild moves the element to the new container, and not just copying it., checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: So I found a bug that was easy enough to fix, just wanted to post about it in case someone in future stumbles across it. Your example allows you to drag an 'obj' onto another 'obj'. Fix was to check the element of ev on drop, super easy. Thanks again!